# How to bind nullable type items to the dropdownlist in razor view?

Tags: entity-framework-5, nullable

I am using MVC4 razor View engine, in my application I am trying to bind list of items to the dropdown list control. For some reasons and to avoid circular references I declared item type is nullable.

**My Model:**

```
public class Curriculum
{
    public int CurriculumID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Year")]
    public int? SchoolYearID { get; set; }        

    public virtual SchoolYear SchoolYears { get; set; }               

}
public class SchoolYear
{
    public int SchoolYearID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="School Year"),MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Curriculum> Curriculums { get; set; }
}
```

*In the above SchoolYearId is a FK and nullable type in Curriculum model.*

**My Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
        ViewBag.SchoolYear = new SelectList(db.SchoolYearRepository.GetAll().ToString(), "SchoolYearID", "Name");
        ViewBag.Subject = new SelectList(db.SubjectRepository.GetAll().ToList(), "SubjectID", "Name");
        return View();
}
```

**My View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SchoolYearID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SchoolYear, "--")
```

*While running my application throwing an error below:*

## DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'SchoolYearID'.

**Question:** how can I resolve this type of problems how to bind nullable type objects to the dropdown list using razor view engine?

Please help me some one!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I am binding a string to your `DropDownList` DataSource

`ViewBag.SchoolYear = new SelectList(db.SchoolYearRepository.GetAll().ToString(), "SchoolYearID", "Name");`

And a string doesn’t have a property SchoolYearID.

It Worked!

`ViewBag.SchoolYear = new SelectList(db.SchoolYearRepository.GetAll().ToList(), "SchoolYearID", "Name");`